# Transferring data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, excel-2016, excel-tables

I have a table where each row represents one logical value.

Sort of like this:

```
| January  | Margaret | 10 |
| February | Jeff     | 20 |
| March    | William  | 30 |
```

I want to transfer the data to another table, where the data would be modelled as following:

```
|          | January | February | March
+----------+---------+----------+------
| Margaret | 10      |          |
| Jeff     |         | 20       |  
| William  |         |          | 30
```

In the case of changes in the Table 1 same changes should be reflected in the Table 2

There are only 4 names and 12 months. Names are repeated A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D.
Numbers are 10-120. Obviously I can use = and click on the cell in the first table but I need more optimal solution. I can't figure it out. Any advise would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your input / expected output more clearly - and show what you have researched / tried already. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Have you tried using `Transpose`? Just copy the table, right click where you want to paste the data and select the Transpose option (4th one over on the list of special pastes).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is called a long to wide transformation. In this case, since you just have months, it might be easiest to create a table with your months as headers (i.e. January - December), and then write a `INDEX/MATCH` formula to fill it in.

Let's say this is your table, starting in cell `A2`

```
Date        Name      Value
January     Jone      1
January     Mike      2
January     Bob       3
February    Jone      4
February    Mike      5
February    Bob       6
```

Then create a table with a header row for the months, starting in `B10`

```
January February    March   April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December
```

And a column for the unique names, starting in `A11`

```
Jone
Mike
Bob
```

So the whole thing looks like this:

```
    January February    March ...
Jone            
Mike            
Bob
```

Then we use an `INDEX/MATCH` formula to fill in the table. Write this in cell `B11`, then fill down and across:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$8,MATCH(1, INDEX(($A11=$B$3:$B$8)*(B$10=$A$3:$A$8),0,1),0))
```

This says, return a value from `C3:C8` where both `A11` and `B10` match in their respective ranges `B3:B8` and `A3:A8`.

You end up with:

```
    January February  ...
Jone    1   4
Mike    2   5
Bob     3   6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get&Transform` to

- Pivot Column 1

  - Advanced Options: Don't Aggregate
  - Values Column:  Column 3

[image]

[image]